# Two Lookups in my SysOperation UiBuilder Error

Tags: x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

When i click my Sa_Type field that is a base enum with Vendor and Customer i want it to fill my second field called combo with all the customer or all the vendors, but this way im receiving the error

> RegisterOverrideMethod was called twice for the same object for method
> 'lookup'. You can only override a method once per instance
> sysoperations

I m overriding a modify in order to know when im clicking for vendor or customer.
Any solutions ?

```
public class AdjustmentUiBuilder extends SysOperationAutomaticUIBuilder
    {
        DialogField type;
        DialogField combo;
        
        
        public void build()
        {
            super();
    
            type = this.bindInfo().getDialogField(this.dataContractObject(), methodStr(AdjustmentSysContract, parmType));
            combo = this.bindInfo().getDialogField(this.dataContractObject(), methodStr(AdjustmentSysContract, parmCombo));
            
            this.modifyDialogFields();
        }
    
        public void postRun()
        {
            type.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormComboBoxControl, modified), methodStr(AdjustmentUiBuilder, moduleCustVend_modified), this);
        }
    
        private void lookupCustAccount(FormStringControl _formStringControl)
        {
            Query query = new Query();
            QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
            SysTableLookup sysTableLookup;
    
            sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(CustTable), _formStringControl);
                
            qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(custTable));
    
            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum), true);
            sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
            sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
        }
    
        private void lookupVendor(FormStringControl _formStringControl)
        {
            Query query = new Query();
            QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
            SysTableLookup sysTableLookup;
    
            sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(VendTable), _formStringControl);
                
            qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(vendTable));
    
            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(VendTable, AccountNum), true);
            sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
            sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
        }
    
        private boolean moduleCustVend_modified(FormComboBoxControl _control)
        {
            this.modifyDialogFields();
    
            return _control.modified();
        }
    
        private void modifyDialogFields()
        {
            if(type.value() == Sa_Type::Customer)
            {         
                    combo.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, lookup), methodStr(AdjustmentUiBuilder, lookupCustAccount), this);
            }
            else
            {
                    combo.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, lookup), methodStr(AdjustmentUiBuilder, lookupVendor), this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i think you need to debug your `modifyDialogFields()`.   How often is it used, and what does it really do  (does it do what you are expecting, or something different....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i was thinking this wrong, and with the old code i was doing two overrides to the same dialog. This is the solution i got to fill my lookups.

```
public void postRun()
    {
       
        account.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, lookup), methodStr(AdjustmentUiBuilder, lookupAccount), this);
        item.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, lookup), methodStr(AdjustmentUiBuilder, lookupAccountItem), this);
        reason.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormStringControl, lookup), methodStr(AdjustmentUiBuilder, lookupReason), this);
    }

    private void lookupAccount(FormStringControl _formStringControl)
    {
        if(type.value() == Sa_Type::Customer)
        {
            Query query = new Query();
            QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
            SysTableLookup sysTableLookup;
            QueryBuildRange         queryBuildRange;
            sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(CustTable), _formStringControl);
            
            qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(custTable));

            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum), true);

            sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
            sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
        }
        else
        {
            Query query = new Query();
            QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
            SysTableLookup sysTableLookup;

            sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(VendTable), _formStringControl);
            
            qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(vendTable));

            sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(VendTable, AccountNum), true);
            sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
            sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the call of the super() method is missed in the postRun().